# Using about pool.apply_async

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new to python, and I want to use `pool.apply_async()` to calibrate my code. The parameters of `pool.apply_async()` confused me.

Here is my code:

```
def detect(i, pdf):
    savefig2pdf.save(event['value'][0][5000:6000],
                 event['value'][1][5000:6000],
                 event['value'][2][5000:6000],
                 event['start point index']+5000 ,
                 eventlist[i],
                 p_result,
                 s_arrival,
                 pdf)"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf = PdfPages('cut_figure.pdf')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)    # set the processes max number 10
    for i in range(0, len(eventlist)):
        pool.apply_async(detect, (i, pdf,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pdf.close()
```

If I only pass the `i`, it works. How can I also pass the pdf to processes? I need the pdf to be able to write until all the process is done. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are seeing? Can you show the first few lines of `detect`?

Comment: actually there is no error message...if i only pass i to detect, it works fine. if i pass pdf and i, code do not process the detect function

Comment: I think it happens when sharing the `pdf` object across multiple processes. or your `detect` function could be throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The `multiprocessing` module relies on `pickle` to serialize the object you pass between your functions. But you cannot pickle the `pdf` object:

```
>>> from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
>>> import pickle
>>> pdf = PdfPages('cut_figure.pdf')
>>> pickle.dumps(pdf)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e06adaa58666> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.dumps(pdf)

TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedWriter' object
```

So it is not possible to use `multiprocessing` with a single `pdf` object. You can try using `threading` to get multi threaded execution, as your program seems to be IO bound (you spend a lot of time writing to a file).